# Unexpected end of file error shell script

Tags: shell

I have the following shell script with finds all the files and then should insert the filenames in to the database. The only problem I have is that I keep getting the error:

```
./testDBScript.sh: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I am trying to insert in to a mysql database from my script using the following code in a loop like:

```
for filename in `find . \! -name [*./]` 
do
    echo "$filename"
    insert_statement_for_db="insert into files(filename) VALUES(\"$filename\");"    
    mysql -h $db_host -u $db_user -D $db_database << finish
    $insert_statement_for_db
    finish
done
```

How else could I insert in to the database? As tutorials online lead me to that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of here-documents is:

```
<<finish
    here-document
finish
```

No indentation before `finish`.

Answer (score 3):

It may be due to missing semicolon after the list of values `for` should iterate over. Try replacing the corresponding line with

```
for filename in `find . \! -name [*./]`;
```

kev's note on here-documents is also right. You can either change indentation or use the alternative format:

```
<<-finish
    here-document
finish
```

In this case the final `finish` can be preceded by tabs (but spaces still won't work).

Comment: kev's answer didn't work for me, but using >>-finish worked. Thanks.